# Interesting redirect

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have a client that has a site which appears to have been hacked or something. I have the responsibility of trying to fix the issue.

```
www.[hatchachalink removed].com
```

Where would i look to fix the issue, in the htaccess of something

Comment: Yeah, if you think I'm going to visit a web site "that appears to be hacked or something"...

Comment: the site just redirects you to a new location, some porn site or something

Comment: 99% of the time, these sort of things are because the people in charge let the domain expire, and a spammer grabbed it.

Comment: The other one percent of the time it's because the person complaining mispelt their own domain.

Comment: Yeah, you should probably add to the question what exactly is wrong, so people have am idea of what they will get if they click the link. People don't want to be surprised. Particularly if they are browsing from work.

Comment: Does your client run a beijing escort service? They have `many beautiful, fluent English girl.`

Comment: Nuke it from orbit, and restore the data.  It is the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good news is that it doesn't seem to be the domain itself that got taken, the admin contact seems still to be your client:

```
Administrative Contact:
americaxl
Jesse Fisher ....
```

This is very good: You have no chance to forcibly get the domain back after it's been dropped and re-registered.

The site is sending a `301 Moved` redirect to the Beijing escort site.

Seeing as the domain name still resolves to a Bluehost server `70.40.208.144`, and assuming this is where your client runs his site, it doesn't look like the DNS settings have been hijacked: I would say the FTP or web hosting account has been hacked in some way and altered to send out the 301 redirect - either through a PHP script ("Header: Location...") or (that would be my gut feeling) through a setting in the hosting company's control panel.

The first step should be trying to log on to the FTP account and confirming whether that is the case.

Comment: I am logged into the Ftp what should i be looking for

Comment: @John an index.php that does a header redirect to the beijing site.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is use `dig` or `host` to see if the IP of the site is the correct IP.  In this case, the IP belongs to "hostmonster.com".  If that's not your web host, then somebody has hijacked your DNS.  If it is, then the problem is either with hostmonster.com, or with your own setup on hostmonster.com.